# How to insert values in history table which has (SEQUENCE_NO) as Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

What I want is, while inserting the data into the main table. I am first inserting its old data to its history table. The history table has more 2 columns of what main table has, which is `HISTSEQ_NO` and `HIST_DATE`.

So, while inserting with my below code. I am getting error as

> ORA-00947: not enough values

So, how to handle the `SEQUENCE` part?

```
string queryInsert;
        queryInsert = "insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h select sysdate, t.* from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL t";
        OracleConnection conInsert = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
        OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand();
        string allQueries = queryInsert;
        cmd1.CommandText = allQueries;
        cmd1.Connection = conInsert;
        conInsert.Open();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Script of the table**

```
CREATE TABLE XXCUS.XXACL_PN_LEASES_ALL_H
    (
      HISTSEQ_NO                   NUMBER           NOT NULL,
      HIST_DATE                    DATE             NOT NULL,
      MKEY                         NUMBER,
      LEASE_ID                     NUMBER,
      LAST_UPDATE_DATE             DATE             NOT NULL,
      LAST_UPDATED_BY              NUMBER           NOT NULL,
      CREATION_DATE                DATE             NOT NULL,
      CREATED_BY                   NUMBER           NOT NULL,
      LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN            NUMBER,
      LEASE_NUM                    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
      PARENT_LEASE_ID              NUMBER,
      ADDRESS_LOCATION_ID          NUMBER,
      LEASE_TYPE_CODE              VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
      PAYMENT_TERM_PRORATION_RULE  NUMBER,
      ABSTRACTED_BY_USER           NUMBER           NOT NULL,
      COMMENTS                     VARCHAR2(240 BYTE),
      STATUS                       VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
      ORG_ID                       NUMBER(15)       DEFAULT NULL,
      LEASE_CLASS_CODE             VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
      LEASE_STATUS                 VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
      CUSTOMER_ID                  NUMBER(15),
      DELETE_FLAG                  CHAR(1 BYTE),
      PROJECT_ID                   NUMBER,
      BUILDING_ID                  NUMBER,
      FLOOR_ID                     NUMBER,
      FLAT_ID                      NUMBER,
      CARPET_AREA                  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
      SALEABLE_AREA                VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
      FLAT_TYPE                    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
      FLAT_STATUS                  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
      FLAT_SUBSTATUS               VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
      CEF_MKEY                     NUMBER,
      BOOKING_NO                   NUMBER,
      ASSIGNED_TO                  NUMBER,
      APPROVER_LAVEL               NUMBER,
      PDC_TYPE                     VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
      IS_MIGRATED                  CHAR(1 BYTE),
      SYS_CREATION_DATE            DATE,
      F_UPDATED_BY                 NUMBER,
      F_FOLLOWUP_DATE              DATE,
      F_ACTIVITY_ID                NUMBER,
      F_SUB_ACTIVITY_ID            NUMBER,
      F_FOLLOWUP_TYPE_ID           NUMBER,
      F_NEXT_FOLLOW_UP_DATE        DATE,
      F_NEXT_ACTIVITY_ID           NUMBER,
      F_NEXT_SUB_ACTIVITY_ID       NUMBER,
      F_REMARKS                    VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
      F_FOLLOWUP_SR_NO             NUMBER,
      F_REASSIGN_REASON            NUMBER(10),
      USER_TYPE                    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
      LOCATION_ID                  NUMBER(10),
      F_LAST_UPDATE_DATE           DATE,
      F_TASK_ID                    NUMBER(10),
      F_TASK_SR_NO                 NUMBER(10),
      BOOKING_DATE                 DATE,
      INV_DATE                     DATE,
      LOAN_DETAILS                 VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
      AUTO_GEN_BILLING             VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
      ADF                          VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
      SALES_USER_ID                NUMBER(10),
      PREDEFINED_CUST              CHAR(1 BYTE),
      SCHEME_ID                    NUMBER(10),
      LOCK_PERIOD                  NUMBER(10),
      NO_OF_DAYS                   NUMBER(10),
      TYPE_OF_BOOKING              VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
      RENTFREE_PERIOD              DATE,
      FREE_NO_DAYS                 VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
      LOI_DATE                     DATE
)
```

Comment: Is HISTSEQ_NO auto increment?

Comment: @BobBrinks: yes, it is auto incremented..

Comment: @nad Oracle doesn't have auto increment columns. You need to use sequence.

If you are owner of XXCUS schema. You can create sequence and use it for getting unique values.  Otherwise ask your DBA for create sequence.

Comment: @Surename: I used the sequence but I am getting error as **Invalid Identifier**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you already added values `sysdate` for one additional column `HIST_DATE`. Now you need add value for secondary column `HISTSEQ_NO`. Do you have sequence for table `xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h` or may be you have another sequence which you can use?

For example, if you have sequence `my_seq`, you can use it in your query:

```
insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h 
    select 
        my_seq.nextval, sysdate, t.* 
    from 
        xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL t
```

But keep in mind order of columns

Comment: I am adding like this `insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h select HISTSEQ_NO.next_val, sysdate, t.* from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL t";` but getting error as **ORA-00904: "HISTSEQ_NO"."NEXT_VAL": invalid identifier**

Comment: @nad Is `HISTSEQ_NO` a sequence?

Comment: i have no idea about oracle, how to check whether it is sequence or not ?

Comment: I got the sequence no, but I am getting error as **ORA-00904: "XXACL_PN_LEASES_ALL_SEQ"."NEXT_VAL": invalid identifier** with this query `insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h select XXACL_PN_LEASES_ALL_SEQ.next_val, sysdate, t.* from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL t`

Comment: @nad 
Ups, it my mistake. Use `XXACL_PN_LEASES_ALL_SEQ.nextval`

Comment: thanks surename, now it worked. Coz of that I wasted my 2 hours. :P

Answer (score 0):

Change the insert query to include the fields you want to insert (excluding the autoincrement value)

```
queryInsert = "insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h(<insert column names here>) select sysdate, t.* from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL t";
```

The ordering of the column names is important here.